# Display a description for each select option

Tags: jquery

I have run into a problem and would appreciate help devising a creative, and lightweight approach around it. I need to show descriptive text every time user selects on option from a select list. I would use something like:

jQuery

```js
$('#machines').change(function() {
  var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');
  $('#description').html($selected.data('description'));
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="machines">Machines</label>
  <select id="machines" class="form-control">
    <option data-description="Printer">Printer</option>
    <option data-description="Copy">Copy</option>
    <option data-description="Scanner">Scanner</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <span id="description"></span>
</div>


<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text-javascript">
    $('#machines').change(function() {
        var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('#description').html($selected.data('description'));
    }).trigger('change');
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?  (Despite being somewhat verbose)

Comment: This code seems to work, where is the problem? @Mahmoud Khosravi

Comment: No, Do not Working. my code

Comment: You need to supply more information than "it's not working".  What behavior do you expect?  What are you seeing that is wrong?

Comment: It works here. The title mentions Bootstrap, but there's no Bootstrap code in the question.

Comment: Yes, I use bootstrap 4.3.1. Can fix the problem? and I update my post.

Comment: Try this $('#description').html($selected.data('data-description'));

Comment: @Thamarai  I changed it but My problem has not yet been resolved

Comment: Problem lies in this line:
`var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');` you are using `var` and `$` all together.
try this code:

`$('#machines').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('#description').html(selected.data('description'));
    }).trigger('change');`

Comment: @PintuKumar  I changed it but My problem has not yet been resolved

Comment: @MahmoudKhosravi don't just copy and paste the same comment over and over again, what is actually happening and what is that you want ? I tried your snippet and it works perfectly fine _(though you removed the cnd link to jquery file, i fixed and tried, it works)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the function is executed before the document is ready.
Try to use document.ready function like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#machines').change(function() {
        var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('#description').html($selected.data('description'));
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: I changed it but My problem has not yet been resolved